# RMI after bind, can i change the object that is bind?

Tags: java, rmi

on Server side after

```
Server server = new Server();
registry.rebind("Server", server);
```

since i have a reference of that Server Object, if i change any field in the server of that object, will it affect the object i bind on the registry? or they are just the same object, RMI just obtain a refernece of my object?

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually, the object that is in the registry is just a delegate for the real server object; clients will just see the methods exposed through the remote interface, and not the internal state represented by the fields (or anything they reference). Practically, the registry actually contains a serialized reference; it is converted to a delegate object when returned to the client as part of the machinery behind the Registry's `lookup` method. The object you get back is *never* the actual server object; it's always just a proxy. Binding just puts a reference into the registry (`bind` does “create or error”, `rebind` does “create or replace”).

In other words, when you change the state of your server object, all other clients will then be able to see the effects of that state change automatically. Because the RMI implementation is multi-threaded, your server object *must* use appropriate locking to avoid hazards. (What's appropriate? Depends on the details of the application, of course.)

Comment: Almost correct. The Registry contains the same stub that the client gets, not an intermediate 'serialized reference' that is 'converted to a delegate object when returned to the client' as 'part of the machinery behind the Registry's lookup method'. There is no such machinery. The Registry is really just another RMI remote object, there are no special mechanics into or out of it at all. +1 when you fix that. Actually it's completely irrelevant to the question: maybe you should just delete it.